# using doseq with bool function

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure.

Lets say I have a simple `doseq` code:

```
(doseq [keyval db] (f keyval))
```

`f` is a Bool function, and I want to know if all the iterations returned TRUE.
It's just like evaluating `and` operator for each sequence.

How can I check the results for each iteration and use it after the `doseq` ,
and  what is the best way to do it?

Example:

```
(and (f? :a db) (f? :b db)...)
```

Comment: doseq is likely not what you are searching for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doseq` is for when the body is just intended to produce side effects per element.

Your example should be implemented with `every?`:

```
(every? f db)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to map and filter a collection to search for different things, hopefully these examples give you some ideas:

```
user> (def db {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4})
#'user/db 
user> (map (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) db) 
(false false true true) 
user> (filter (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) db) 
([:b 2] [:d 4])
```

There are several ways to see if they are all true:

```
user> (reduce #(and %1 %2) 
              (map (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) 
                    {:a 2 :b 4 :c 6}))                                             
true 
user> (reduce #(and %1 %2) (map (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) db)) 
false  

user> (not-any? false? (map (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) db)) 
false 
user> (not-any? false? (map (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) {:a 2 :b 4 :c 6}))
true
```

And look at the db for other things:

```
user> (filter (fn [[k v]] (if (even? v) true false)) {:a 2 :b 4 :c 6})
([:a 2] [:c 6] [:b 4])  
user> (filter (fn [[k v]] (if (odd? v) true false)) {:a 2 :b 4 :c 6})
()
user> (if (empty? (filter (fn [[k v]] (if (odd? v) true false)) {:a 2 :b 4 :c 6})) "all where even" "some where odd")
"all where even"
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to evaluate every term but only up until the first false. If I get what you are asking for, try [some](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some).

```
; assuming f? and db in scope

(defn all-are-f [aseq] (not (some #(not (f? % db)) aseq)))
```